Can a US president put a substantial tariff on cars made in Mexico, within the confines of USMCA?
For example, Trump recently said he plans to put a 100% tariff on cars assembled in Mexico.
Anything is possible possible if one throws away or renegotiates existing treaties, but can such a tariff be imposed within the confines of USMCA (the Trump-renegotiated NAFTA)?

FWTW, sometimes he said 200%, according to Reuters, but that probably changes little as far as this Q goes.

Research would include if there are already existing tariffs between Mexico and the US on cars and if in USMCA maybe limits on the heights of tariffs are set.

Not without a modification of the treaty and approval from Congress.
Per the link in the question:

The Agreement between the United States of America, Mexico, and Canada
(USMCA) is a free trade agreement among the United States, Mexico, and
Canada. It replaced the North American Free Trade Agreement (NAFTA)
implemented in 1994, and is sometimes characterized as "NAFTA 2.0", or
"New NAFTA", since it largely maintains or updates the provisions of
its predecessor. USMCA is one of the world's largest free trade zones,
with a population of more than 510 million people and an economy of
$30.997 trillion in nominal GDP — nearly 30 percent of the global
economy.
All sides came to a formal agreement on October 1, 2018, and U.S.
president Donald Trump proposed USMCA during the G20 Summit the
following month, where it was signed by himself, Mexican President
Enrique Peña Nieto, and Canadian Prime Minister Justin Trudeau. A
revised version reflecting additional consultations was signed on
December 10, 2019, and ratified by all three countries, with Canada
being the last to ratify on March 13, 2020. Following notification by
all three governments that the provisions were ready for domestic
implementation, the agreement came into effect on July 1, 2020.
USMCA is primarily a modernization of NAFTA, namely concerning
intellectual property and digital trade,[18][19] and borrows language
from the Comprehensive and Progressive Agreement for Trans-Pacific
Partnership (CPTPP), of which Canada and Mexico are signatories. Key
changes from its predecessor include increased environmental and
working regulations; greater incentives for automobile production in
the U.S. (with quotas for Canadian and Mexican automotive production)
. . .
Automobile rules of origin (ROO) requirements mandate that a certain
portion of an automobile's value must come from within the governed
region. In NAFTA, the required portion was 62.5 percent. The USMCA
increases this requirement by 12.5 percentage points, to 75 percent of
the automobile's value. The initial proposal from the Trump
administration was an increase to 85 percent and an added stipulation
that 50 percent of the automotive content be made by United States
auto manufacturers. While the deal's text did not include the more
demanding version of this provision, there is concern that the
increased domestic sourcing, aimed at promoting U.S. employment, will
come with higher input costs and disruptions to existing supply
chains.

It was ratified in 2020 and has a sixteen year term. It was ratified as a treaty and has been implemented as necessary by Congress.
NAFTA eliminated tariffs on Mexican origin automobiles and the USMCA didn't change that (except to tweak some place of origin rules and to set a quota on maximum automotive imports from Canada and Mexico which haven't been an issue so far). So, without abrogating the treaty, which would require Congressional approval, tariffs on Mexican origin automobiles are prohibited by law.
It is hardly partisan to note that Mr. Trump's public statements on the campaign trail are often not factually correct. And, it is also , in any case, not unusual for a political candidate to promise to do something that can only be achieved with legislative and/or international diplomatic cooperation.

Can you be more specific? Does USMCA set the car tariffs to a precise value? Are there not 'safeguards' etc. he could invoke (claiming Mexico was dumping, for instance)?

The USMCA sets car tariffs from Mexico to the precise value of zero (just as NAFTA did). He can't invoke "safeguards", etc.

FWTW though, it seems that not all mfg fit the ROO profile https://sgp.fas.org/crs/row/IF12082.pdf Also interesting "Since USMCA’s entry into force, Mexico and Canada have
disputed the U.S. interpretation of the RVC [regional value content] calculation
method. In December 2022, a USMCA dispute settlement
panel ruled against the United States. The three countries
have stated that they are continuing to work towards a
resolution. The USMCA panel decision cannot be appealed." I guess that gives Trump some ammo to claim "USMCA is very unfair" and scrap it.

"Very unfair" is a far cry from "I can increase tariffs to 200%".

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Wasn't USMCA Trump's creation, to fix the broken NAFTA? Now he's claiming it's "very unfair"?

@Barmar: I'm sure he can blame the deep state for inserting a bad arbitration clause that ruined the whole thing. I mean, how can it be fair if Trump himself doesn't get to appoint the arbitration panels?

To be fair, NAFTA was every bit as much a congressional approved treaty, and he ditched it last time he became President. I don't see what's stopping him from doing the same thing again if he becomes President again. If anything, past behavior ought to be taken as indicative of likely future behavior.

I guess he can raise the tariffs to 200% of the current tariffs (200% of zero is still zero).

When we are talking about confressional aproval, are we just talking about the Senate since its a treaty, or does the House also get involved in this?

@SMSTJ The whole of Congress could pass an ordinary law that overrules a treaty within the confines of U.S. Constitutional law. But a duly enacted self-executing treaty can override an existing statute. If Congressional statutes have ben enacted to implement USMCA, those statutes would have to be modified by an ordinary law or by a new treaty adopted by 2/3rds of the Senate.

@ohwilleke thank you very much
