Could the American president impose a 25% tariff on Mexican and Canadian goods by executive order?
The provisions of the free trade United States–Mexico–Canada Agreement include proportions of various goods that can be traded without tariffs between the countries.
President Trump has just announced:

On January 20th, as one of my many first Executive Orders, I will sign all necessary documents to charge Mexico and Canada a 25% Tariff on ALL products coming into the United States.

Can he do that? Isn't that a legally binding treaty?

Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89173/can-a-us-president-put-a-substantial-tariff-on-cars-made-in-mexico-within-the-c He'll probably have to scrap USMCA. But US presidents have held they can unilaterally scrap treaties that were approved by the Senate. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32843/how-many-treaties-did-us-presidents-terminate-without-congress-approval

This question had a pretty rough ride, spending a lot of time at -2. Ditto the first answers, which also seemed reasonable enough.  I wonder what that was about.  Pro-Trumpies?  Anti-Trumpies?  Hard to guess, at least on the question.

@ItalianPhilosopher May be because I self-answered which may be seen as rep-whoring; and because there appear to be obvious historical counterexamples I was originally not aware of. The issue is at least a bit more complex than I initially thought (may depend on the exact way the treaty came to be, and on additional congress resolutions or laws giving (possibly blanket) authorization). Some of it is also up to the branches; POTUS routinely refuses to hear power play squabbles (political prerogative).

@ItalianPhilosopher And then there is also what is described by a term I had never heard before, "historical gloss"; part of the constitution is interpreted through the way it is lived. If congress does not complain, the president's executive power grows and congress's shrinks (and vice versa, one may presume).

Ah, self-answer within a very short time will do it, I guess.  That seems mostly a fancy term for precedent.  But just because it wasn't challenged at a time does not mean it can't be later on so it's not really precedent as such.  With this court?  Who knows.

@ItalianPhilosopher Self-answering is frowned upon but I find it totally fine; I was curious about Trump's announcements, researched it, found clear answers and wanted to share it. That's explicitly encouraged. If people like it, I'm happy; if they don't I am curious what they found. (I also refrained from putting "Trump" in the title which would probably have attracted more attention because it is irrelevant to the legal question.)

I’m voting to close this question because this question should be asked on law.stackexchange.com and not on politics

This question is similar to: What gives the U.S. President the legal authority to raise tariffs?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

YMMV

the Reagan Administration gave notice in 1985 of its
termination of a Treaty of Friendship, Commerce, and Navigation with
Nicaragua, and the treaty terminated the following year.
[...] A federal district court subsequently applied the political question doctrine to dismiss a challenge to this termination.

The relevant clause is probably


Either Party may, by giving one year's written notice to the other Party, terminate the present Treaty at the end of the initial ten-year period or at any time thereafter.


It doesn't say who in US could terminate the treaty. So Reagan did it, and the courts upheld it.
USMCA does have a similar enough clause

Article 34.6: Withdrawal
A Party may withdraw from this Agreement by providing written notice of withdrawal to
the other Parties. A withdrawal shall take effect six months after a Party provides written notice
to the other Parties. If a Party withdraws, this Agreement shall remain in force for the remaining
Parties.

I don't see why Trump could not "pull a Reagan" on USMCA, Jon Yoo etc. opinions aside.
BTW, NAFTA had a similar provision. And Trump's justice department held that he could single-handedly execute it, with no further Congress involvement.

As for imposing tariffs, Congress has delegated that power in Part to the executive. E.g.

In early 2018 President Trump imposed tariffs on steel and aluminum imports under Section 232 of the Trade Expansion Act of 1962. This law states that the president can raise tariffs on imports that pose a threat to national security. Section 232 allows the President to implement these tariffs without the approval of Congress, following an investigation by the Department of Commerce.

So it will take a little creative use of what is a "threat to national security" to impose new tariffs without consulting Congress. More on that on CBS, for other ways he could do it:

There's also the International Emergency Economic Powers Act (IEEPA), although it hasn't used to restrict trade since President Richard Nixon was in office. The act says: "Any authority granted to the President by ... this title may be exercised to deal with any unusual and extraordinary threat ... to the national security, foreign policy, or economy of the United States, if the President declares a national emergency with respect to such threat."
"The authorities granted to the President ... may only be exercised to deal with an unusual and extraordinary threat with respect to which a national emergency ..." it adds in part.
In other words, in order to use IEEPA to impose tariffs, Trump would have to declare a national emergency through an executive order, claiming that a U.S. trading partner posed a major threat.

There's also Section 338 of the Tariff Act of 1930 that is sufficiently vague/broad to allow executive action without Congress involvement.
Also Trump used "section 201" to put tariffs on washing machines and solar panels, again without Congress involvement. These are "on goods entering the United States that injure or threaten to injure domestic industries producing like goods", in accordance to the Trade Act of 1974. Trump also used section 301 of the same act to impose broad tariffs on China. That section allows tariffs on
countries that do things judged by the administration as

“unjustifiable” or “unreasonable” and burden U.S.
commerce.

Again, pretty broad language. BTW, from your story, Trump said he'd put those tariffs on Canada and Mexico conditionally:

he would impose a 25% tariff on Canada and Mexico until they clamp down on drugs, particularly fentanyl, and migrants crossing the border.

Will courts punt on it as a political question if he e.g. uses section 301 with that justification? We shall see. Apparently there are some section 301 lawsuit still bubbling through the system. So, anyhow, it will probably take years for the courts to counteract any executive orders of this kind.

No, he couldn't. Regulating commerce is the prerogative of Congress (Article I, Section 8, Clause 3: "The Congress shall have Power ... To regulate Commerce with foreign Nations.") Regarding NAFTA, which is the predecessor of the USMCA currently in force, Paul J. Larkin Jr., Senior Legal Research Fellow at the Institute for Constitutional Government of the Heritage Foundation, wrote::

If a Free Trade Agreement went through the Bicameralism and Presentment process and the president signed it, it is a “Law,” and the president cannot disregard it. (Paul J. Larkin Jr., Senior Legal Research Fellow, Institute for Constitutional Government, The Heritage Foundation).

In the same article, Julian Ku, law professor, Hofstra University Law School, and John Yoo, law professor, UC Berkeley, are quoted:

Like all modern trade pacts, NAFTA is a congressional-executive agreement created by statute, not treaty. Trump cannot terminate it — or even renegotiate it — without the approval of Congress.

John Yoo's opinion is of particular relevance because he sees very little constraints of presidential power in other circumstances.

SCOTUS might say otherwise. Come to think of it, it would be a better Q if US presidents have unilaterally scrapped any trade treaties in the past. I know they scrapped some treaties, including Congress approved ones, but IDK if any were trade ones.

@264champagnebottlesonice But that would require another RV.

Anyhow, SCOTUS said he can break the law with no consequences to himself, as long as it's an official act. That does not (yet) extend to his subordinates carrying out such orders, but only because that kind of case hasn't made it to SCOTUS yet.

@264champagnebottlesonice Yeah, that was the first RV. Such a scenario is also a grey zone: "Can" in the question may be understood factually or legally. The two may diverge.

@264champagnebottlesonice That means he's safe from criminal prosecution. Jurisdiction issues between branches of the federal government are civil actions.

@264champagnebottlesonice there has never been a time in the US when a president's purporting to impose a tariff that was unauthorized by congress would have led to any consequences for the president.  The only thing that would happen would be a court finding that the tariff is invalid and ordering that it not be enforced, and probably that any changes to the published tariff be undone.  Nothing in the recent immunity opinion changes any of that.

Please review the Trade Expansion Act of 1962.

@DrunkCynic: Right but if that conflicts with a free trade agreement passed by Congress, then which one takes precedence? Would a free trade agreement passed after 1962 override any conflicting authority from the Trade Expansion Act of 1962?

No, he couldn't.  Not so fast:  USMCA Article 32.2: Essential Security: "1. Nothing in this Agreement shall be construed to: ... preclude a Party from applying measures that it considers necessary for the
fulfilment of its obligations with respect to the maintenance or restoration of
international peace or security, or the protection of its own essential security
interests."

@JustMe "A Party" here means "a signatory country"; how each country internally makes their decisions, e.g. in exercising these exceptions, is up to their respective constitution (hopefully).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/19/1862  Also see https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/IF/IF10667  "Threaten national security" is a pretty broad and highly malleable term.
